# Regular expressions, using an expression in Python with a space involved

Tags: python

I generated this expression, after reading the documentation:

```
(\['[^']+'(?:,\s*'[^']+'){0,}\]) (\[(?:'[^']+')(?:,\s*'[^']+'){0,}\]) ('[^']+') ([1-9][0-9]*)
```

It is meant to recognise such pattern:

> ['1','11','111'] ['cpp','h'] 'utf-8' 500

I tried to use it in Python 3.5.4:

```
import re
import sys
x = sys.argv[1:]
args = re.match(u"(\['[^']+'(?:,\s*'[^']+'){0,}\]) (\['[^']+'(?:,\s*'[^']+'){0,}\]) ('[^']+') ([1-9][0-9]*)",
                ' '.join(x))
```

I can recognize this example:

> ['1','11','111'] ['cpp','h'] 'utf-8' 500

However when trying to recognize this:

> ['1', '11', '111'] ['cpp', 'h'] 'utf-8' 500

or this:

> ['1','1 1','1 11'] ['cp p','h'] 'utf-8' 500

in python it fails, whenever a space is represented in between `(')` and `(')` or between `(',)` and `(')`.

But on this [site](https://regex101.com/r/eA5jB2/198) the regex works like a charm.

Any idea why is this so?

Comment: I am trying to make this project available through __main__
https://github.com/MNTsay/re-encoder.git

Comment: You really need to use a raw string (`r"..."`) to make sure the backslashes in your regex don't get misinterpreted as string escape characters.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it really saved a lot of my pain, when entering '\\' in every address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am soory, noob's mistake, first project in python.

I totaly forgot that in cmd I should include text using ' " ' whenever it contains spaces.

**wrong way:**

> python re-encoder.py ['1','11','11 1'] ['cpp','h'] 'utf-8' 500

**right way:**

> python re-encoder.py "['1', '1 1', '11 1']" "['cpp','h']" 'utf-8' 500

to call the script in cmd

Comment: If you're passing these string directly into Python, you don't have to use regex to parse them, use `ast.literal_eval`: `ast.literal_eval("'utf-8'") == 'utf-8'`.

Comment: I am willing to do it, the regexp is more like an evaluation for valid arguments.
thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

Passing parameters as strings will work.
Why not do that?

```
import re
import sys
x = sys.argv[1:]
args = re.match(u"(\['[^']+'(?:,\s*'[^']+'){0,}\]) (\['[^']+'(?:,\s*'[^']+'){0,}\]) ('[^']+') ([1-9][0-9]*)",
                ' '.join(x))

g = args.groups()
print(g[0])
print(g[1])
print(g[2])
print(g[3])
```

try this.

```
$ python re-encoder.py "['1', '11', '111'] ['cpp', 'h'] 'utf-8' 500"
```

result

```
['1', '11', '111']
['cpp', 'h']
'utf-8'
500
```

Comment: Thank you, I totaly missed the idea to pass them all as a one string.
Since I was consedering to make some of them optional, and use getopt.